# Why does require.js seem to be loading all my modules on initial page load?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am developing a single page backbone app using requirejs, and today when I deployed to our beta server, I discovered that the initial page load was around 20 seconds while it fetched all the scripts.

I assumed this was because I was using the dependency array when defining modules like so:

```
define([
    'ui',
    'models/user',
    'collections/campaigns',
    'collections/groups',
    'collections/keywords',
    'collections/inboxes',
    'collections/templates',
    'collections/contacts',
    'router'
], function (Ui, UserDetails, Campaigns, Groups, Keywords, Inboxes, Templates, Contacts, Router) {

    return {
        start: function () {
            // ...
            // initialize and start app
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Which I believed meant that when the main application module was loaded, every other script would be loaded, due to the fact that every single module was using this method.

I then changed the method of fetching modules to get them as I needed them by calling `require('...')` directly when I need them like this:

```
define(function (require) {
    return Backbone.Router(function () {
        // ...
        // route initializtion etc
        // ...

        inbox: function (routeVar) {
            var InboxView = require('InboxView');
            this.inboxView = new InboxView();
            // render view etc
        }
    });
});
```

However to my surprise, upon running the app again and checking the network tab of chromes developer console - I saw that as before the application is fetching all of my modules, and I am getting the same page load time.

Am I completely missing the point here? As I was under the impression that the scripts would be fetched upon each call of require. Is that not right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to asynchronously load AMD modules you must call require and provide a function callback that will be called when the requested module has been loaded:

```
require(['InboxView'], function(InboxView) {
  // Do something with InboxView here...
});
```

The sample code you provided called `require('InboxView')` in a synchronous style.  Because you are using the "[sugar](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar)" syntax, RequireJS will inspect your code, find any synchronous calls to `require()` and add those dependencies to the top-level dependency list of the module, in effect giving you this:

```
define(['require', 'InboxView'], function (require) {
  return Backbone.Router(function () {
    // ...
    // route initializtion etc
    // ...

    inbox: function (routeVar) {
        var InboxView = require('InboxView');
        this.inboxView = new InboxView();
        // render view etc
    }
  });
});
```

...hence why you saw all modules loaded immediately.

Add the async callback to require and you should be fine.  Also, if you think about it, how would your code work if RequireJS waited to load the module for `InboxView` until your route fired without the `require` call blocking until the load was complete?  :)

Comment: well I actually thought it would block while it loaded the scripts, thanks for the info I'll look into it

Comment: cheers for the reply, doing an asynchronous request as you suggested has solved my problem. i have now drastically reduced my initial page load. thanks a lot!

Comment: what's the meaning of "['require', 'InboxView']" ? I never saw something like this. Thanks.

Comment: @VladNicula Requiring `require` tells requireJS to provide the module with a properly scoped instance of the require function that it can use to require further modules.  Proper scoping is important if you make use of things like [multi-version support](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion) so require loads the correct versions of requested modules.  In this particular instance, the list of required modules was automatically generated by requireJS due to use of the [sugar syntax](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar).

Comment: @dormisher Can you elaborate on what your final solution was?  I've tried the above code and a) it doesn't work since there is no syntax `require('InboxView', function(InboxView) {})` and b) conceptually speaking there is no such thing as a 'synchronous' require call.  All require calls are asynchronous.

Comment: @TNguyen sorry, the `'InboxView'` should have been wrapped in `[]` in the first example. Fixed.